# 'Unhandled exception' when trying to set up a HttpURLConnection in android studio

Tags: java, android, web-services, android-studio

I try to set up a HttpURLConnection. I use the syntax from the [Google documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html). I want to send the string 'phonenumber' and the string 'password' to a webserver. This is my .java file:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        EditText phonenumberText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.phonenumberText);
        EditText passwordText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.passwordText);
        String phonenumber = phonenumberText.getText().toString();
        String password = passwordText.getText().toString();
        String web = "webadress/login/tel=" + phonenumber + "&password =" + password;

        URL url = new URL(web);
        HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        try{
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
            readStream(in);
            finally {
                client.disconnect();
            }//finally
        }//try

    }//onCreate
}//Login
```

In the AndroidManifest I included

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

But I get for the methods `url.openConnection()`, `client.getInputStream()` and `readStream(in)` the error **Unhandled exception: java.io.IOException**. For `new URL(web)` I get the error **Unhandled exception: java.net.MalformedURLException**. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read this: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html

Comment: You are invoking methods that throw checked exceptions, hence you need to catch them. That's simply how it works.

Comment: I am a beginner: what does it mean to catch method's?

Comment: You are not catching methods, you need to catch the Exceptions that the methods are throwing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the *all* statements which throw an `IoException` in a try / catch block, not just the last two. Something like this:

```
//your existing code..

HttpURLConnection client = null;

try{
    URL url = new URL(web);
    client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(client.getInputStream());
    readStream(in);

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
     //bad  URL, tell the user
} catch (IOException e) {
     //network error/ tell the user
} finally  {
     client.disconnect();
}
```

To be specific: the `catch` blocks are used to "catch" an exception, eg. when there's a network error or the URL is not valid, control is transferred to the `catch` block, from where you could eg. tell the user that there was an error.

Comment: Thank you, but it cannot resolve client. Only in 'client.disconnect()'

Comment: @Izotz, Fixed, sorry. You need to put the `HttpURLConnection client;` outside the catch block

Comment: The variable 'client' in the finally statement 'might not have been initialized'

Comment: @Izotz, Oops fixed again, sorry, Should have been `HttpURLConnection client = null;`